# Open a close a sibling component

Tags: angular

I have a sidebar with a button that when clicked I would like to toggle a variable true or false that then shows/hides a sibling component. I am getting an error `Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'boolean'`. How can I achieve this the correct way?

**sidebar-menu.component.ts**

```
import { Component, EventEmitter, Output } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'sidebar-menu',
  templateUrl: './sidebar-menu.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sidebar-menu.component.styl']
})
export class SidebarMenuComponent {

  showDetails = false;
  @Output()
  onShowDetails: EventEmitter<boolean> = new EventEmitter();

  constructor() {}

  toggleDetails() {
    this.showDetails = !this.showDetails;
    this.onShowDetails.emit(this.showDetails);
    console.log('Sidebar Toggle', this.showDetails);
  }

}
```

**details.component.ts**

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'details',
  templateUrl: './details.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./details.component.styl']
})
export class DetailsComponent {

  @Input() showDetails: boolean;

  constructor() {

  }

}
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.styl']
})
export class AppComponent {
  @Input() showDetails: boolean = false;


  constructor() {
  }

}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<sidebar-menu></sidebar-menu>
<details *ngIf="showDetails"></details>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Comment: You declare showDetails as an EventEmitter, and right after, in the constructor, you initialize it to false. false is not a valid value for a variable of type EventEmitter. Not sure how the message could be clearer.

Comment: Yes it's clear that I can't use a Boolean, thats obvious. Whats not is why and what do I can I do about it. How can I push a true/false value between two components.

Comment: Use your event emitter to... emit events. Listen to these events from the parent component to change the value of the showDetails input of the details component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your showDetails property is not of type boolean, it's type of `EventEmitter<boolean>`, and when you trying to set value like `this.showDetails = false;` it throws error.
Try this:

```
import { Component, EventEmitter, Output } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'sidebar-menu',
  templateUrl: './sidebar-menu.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sidebar-menu.component.styl']
})
export class SidebarMenuComponent {

  showDetails = false;
  @Output()
  onShowDetails: EventEmitter<boolean> = new EventEmitter<boolean>();

  constructor() {    
  }

  toggleTeamDetails() {
    this.showDetails = !this.showDetails;
    this.onShowDetails.emit(this.showDetails);
    console.log('Sidebar Toggle', this.showDetails);
  }    
}
```

And the component which interested in this event should subscribe for this event.

Also if you want use boolean value directly in template you can do this:

```
<sidebar #sidebar>
    <child-component *ngIf="sidebar.showDetails"></child-component>
</sidebar>
<sibling-component *ngIf="sidebar.showDetails"></sibling-component>
```

Comment: I had a go, updated code above. I now get this error `Type 'EventEmitter<{}>' is not assignable to type 'EventEmitter<boolean>'.
  Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.`

Comment: Also my Sidebar and the Details components are both children of App component not of each other so I'm not sure how that would work with `#sidebar`

Comment: I forgot to add <> to EventEmitter, please see updated code. You also can use #variable in sibling nodes. so it looks like: <sidebar #sidebar> </sidebar> <sibling-component *ngIf="sidebar.showDetails"></sibling-component>

Comment: that seems to have worked, I did have to set the event emiter to `<any>` as `<>` created another error. I put together a Plunker here https://plnkr.co/edit/AVQwcIu9mc5mO5BtBcpf how could I now close the details by clicking on the button inside of the details component?

Comment: I think in your case using just eventEmitters is enough, here is updated plunker with only eventEmitters:
https://plnkr.co/edit/A7WaFWZxGnY5sSpDoBSA?p=preview

Comment: Thanks for that, One last thing, in your example the button in the Sidebar no longer closes the panel, it now only opens it. Why the switch from boolean? And if I did want to both the sidebar button and the details close button to close the details panel how could I do that?

Comment: If your sidebar also can close details, you can just change current state when you sidebarComponent emits value: `<app-sidebar (onShowDetails)="showDetails=!showDetails"></app-sidebar>`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128624/discussion-between-daimz-and-nikolai).